# fprintf prints a new line at the beginning of the file

Tags: c, file-io, printf

I'm using a fprintf function to print to a new file

I'm using the following command to write multiple times:

```
fprintf(fp, "%-25s %d %.2f %d",temp->data.name, temp->data.day, temp->data.temp, temp->data.speed);
```

The problem is that sometimes the file gets an extra new line as the first character.
Could this be lelftovers from some buffer, I don't really know...

```
typedef struct Data {
    char name[26];
    int day;
    int speed;
    float temp;
} Data ;
```

@spatz you were right, I'm kind of new to the string format thing and I was told to make one for a fscanf where I was to expect an undetermined amount of space between the bits of data, here is what I came up with, I'm pretty sure its the source of the problem:

```
check=fscanf(fp1, "%20c%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%f%*[^0-9]%d%*[^\n]%*c", name, &day, &temp, &speed);
```

only the first line get read normally and everything afterwards reads the new line of the previous line.

Can someone please show me the proper way to write this thing?

Comment: Show the definition of the type of `temp->data`. Are you compiling with all warnings?

Comment: How is `fp` opened? Could it simply be that `name` starts with a newline?

Comment: please post the full code, or all attempts to solve your problem will be pure speculation. I.e. how do you open the file, does the file exist before, is it open in another program, what is the actual data in your `data` struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling fscanf() over and over, and hoping that the newlines match up how you want, use `fgets()` to get one line at a time, parse it using fscanf(), and do error handling on a line-by-line basis.  This will be less error-prone, and it sounds like it will clear up your problem with no extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `name` starts with a newline, and that newline ends up in the file.

In order to properly parse the file I would have to know its format, but for now I assume it's `<string> <int> <int> <float>` where the number of spaces between each element may vary.

The format string I would start with is simply `"%s%d%d%f"`, and let `fscanf()` deal with the whitespace. With this format string I was able to properly parse lines like

```
foo     3   4 7
```

If this does not satisfy you feel free to elaborate on the format of the file you are parsing and I'll try to come up with solutions.